# PHP and Importing pylab

Tags: php, macos, import, matplotlib, fgets

I have a PHP script that calls in a python program. Here is the php script:

```
<?php
    $last_line = popen('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python test.py', 'r');
    $results = fgets($last_line);
    print $results;
?>
```

and this is the content of test.py:

```
test.py:

    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
    # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    # from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
    # import pylab 

    print "Hello World!"
```

Now, this works fine and I get "Hello World!" in browser. However, if I uncomment any of the imports (i.e., import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, import matplotlib.pyplot as plt or import pylab) I don't get the result from PHP. It will be great if someone could help me with this as I need all the plotting functions from Python.

Comment: Have you tried running just the python file without the comments to see if you get any errors? I'd guess that you don't have pylab and the others installled.

Comment: The python code works just fine in a terminal. And I have all of them installed.

Comment: Any help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The matplotlib part was not getting executed when the python script was executed through php.
Then i just include the following statements in my .py file..

```
import os
os.environ[ 'MPLCONFIGDIR' ] = '/tmp/'

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('agg')
```

and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

No complete answer but perhaps helpful:

Assuming you're on Mac OS, I have changed your `.php` file to to:

```
<br><br>==== Start ====<br><br>

<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $handle = popen('python test.py 2>&1', 'r');
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer."<br>";
    }
    pclose($handle);

?>

<br><br>==== End ====<br><br>
```

and the `.py` file to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print "Hello World!"
```

The `2>&1` redirects the error output of programs to the standard output, this can usefull for debugging purposes.

The result on the page in the browser contained:

> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/matplotlib-0.91.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/matplotlib/**init**.py",
>   line 403, in _get_configdir  raise RuntimeError("Failed to create
>   %s/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory
>   for matplotlib configuration data"%h)  RuntimeError: Failed to create
>   /Library/WebServer/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a
>   writable directory for matplotlib configuration data

Than i did as root:

```
mkdir /Library/WebServer/.matplotlib
chown _www /Library/WebServer/.matplotlib/
```

And than the page in the browser contained as last error:

> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/matplotlib-0.91.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/matplotlib/numerix/ma/**init**.py",
>   line 16, in  from numpy.core.ma import *  ImportError: No module named
>   ma

hmm, thats still disappointing, however you're mileage may vary, the problem has probably to do with the environment/permissions of the webserver user (_www).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jan Kuiken for trying it out! Finally after hard struggle I was able to figure it out. First as suggested in [this page](http://texnological.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-execute-python-matplolib-pylab.html), I added the following to `test.py`:

```
import os
os.environ[ 'MPLCONFIGDIR' ] = '/tmp/'
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

and imported `pylab` (i.e., uncommented it).

This worked from the command line but not in the browser. Then I did a *passthru* and got the following error in the browser:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices...
Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libjpeg.62.dylib
```

I figured out it should be a problem with ImageMagick and followed the suggestions from the following page:
[Getting MAMP 1.9 to work with ImageMagick](http://mikepuchol.com/2010/08/26/getting-mamp-1-9-to-work-with-image-magick-imagick-so-and-other-flora/)

And after correct installation, I was able to get the python code going on. The python code had a command to plot and save the figure and I guess ImageMagick is required in that case!