# Trouble using maptlotlib in web application server (php)

Tags: php, python, matplotlib

I have a python program that starts with:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import math 
#import wx
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
import scipy as scipy
from scipy import *
from scipy import constants
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

It gives me error when I try to open it with php.
I have googled and apparently if I do this before importing pylab or pyplot:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Problem should be solved. But the error I get is:

```
  /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py:923:     UserWarning: This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time
```

Any idea what's going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default backend is specified in the `matplotlibrc` file -- you could try changing it there.

It may also be that whatever environment you are running python in may already import matplotlib and specify the backend as part of the configuration. Also, [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398920/php-and-importing-pylab) post suggest the following line may be needed:

```
os.environ[ 'MPLCONFIGDIR' ] = '/tmp/'
```

Comment: How do you suggest that I change the backend? What should I change it to?

Comment: Try `locate`, you can usually find example matplotlibrc in etc and maybe the default file in .config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc. Also at http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html. matplotlib will preferentially use the version of `.matplotlibrc` in the local directory to define the backend. If the suggestion is `Agg` for php with python, try changing to this. However, it sounds like the backend may be specified elsewhere when called from php. Did the other post at http://texnological.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-execute-python-matplolib-pylab.html not help?